# How to validate by JSON transformers?

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I am using Play Framework 2.2.1 + Scala.
I want to use [JSON coast-to-coast design](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/ScalaJsonTransformers). But I don't understand how to validate incoming JSON.

For example I have some structure:

```
{
  name: "Alice",
  hobby: ["skiing", "biking", "smoking"]
}
```

And I need to check that `hobby` could contains only `"skiing"`, `"biking"`, but not `"smoking"` and `name` is not `null`.
How can I check this?

Here is some code example to modify:

```
val transformer = (
  (__ \ 'name ).json.pickBranch and
  (__ \ 'hobby).json.pickBranch ) reduce

def add = Action(parse.json) { request =>
  request.body.validate(transformer).map{ js =>
    Ok("all right")
  }.recoverTotal{ e =>
    BadRequest("Detected error:"+ JsError.toFlatJson(e))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way would to first define a regex pattern reader based on your requirement of "skiing or biking", then combine that to create the overall transformer:

```
val hobbyReads = Reads.pattern("skiing|biking".r)

val transformer = (
  (__ \ "name").read[String] and
  (__ \ "hobby").read(Reads.seq[String](hobbyReads))
) tupled
```

To actually read the json, I would recommend the fold function:

```
transformer.reads(request.body).fold(
  invalid => BadRequest(JsError.toFlatJson(invalid)),
  valid => Ok("all right")
)
```

Also. be mindful that if you're running any unit tests, make sure that you are using valid JSON (the one in your example is invalid as the keys are missing quotes and there's no comma separating the fields).

Comment: Keys are missing quotes because it is [Scala Symbol](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Symbol). I fixed comma separating the fields, thanks. As I wrote, I want use [JSON coast-to-coast design](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/ScalaJsonTransformers), so I don't want convert JSON to any structure (like `tupled`). I need solution that I can retrieve `JSON` from user, validate it, send `JSON` to database.

Comment: From what I gather, JSON Coast-to-Coast is primarily for transforming JSON in some way.  Your question only asks about validating, which can be done using my reads object.  Did you need to transform the json in any way?